# Python Sqlite3 - Select from table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a list of Colors which is also the columns in my sqlite3 database table. 
At any point an entry is made, a color is selected so it records the date column and one color column, leaving the other columns as null. 
Now I want to call the entry and the Date and append it with the respective Color(column). How should the syntax be like? Can anyone help please?

```
for q in Color:
stmt = "SELECT Date, %s FROM mytable WHERE %s IS NOT NULL" %(q,q)
d.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter? I don't think this tag is needed.

Comment: Sorry. I've taken it off